# XQuery transform date to dateTime tibco

Tags: variables, xpath, format, tibco

I have a variable parameter that is formatted to the date type in XML. I need to convert that parameter into the dateTime format for another variable to accept my copy operation. I tried `tib:format-dateTime("EEE MMM dd zzz 
yyyy",concat($Variable0/root/param,'00:00:00'))` but it doesn't work. How can write the xpath?

Answer (score 0):

```
tib:format-dateTime("EEE MMM dd zzz yyyy", concat("2017-10-23",'T00:00:00'))
```

Comment: Please explain your answer.